# How to swap two rows of a two-dimensional array, and why would it work?

Tags: arrays, delphi, row, swap

**Summarization:**

Please check the comments below from David, Uwe, and other experts.

================================================================================

The following code swaps two rows in a two-dimensional, dynamic array of double values. I am wondering: (1) whether the following code is a best practice of swapping two rows of a two-dimensional array? If not, then what is the best practice to do this kind of job? (2) why would the following code work? I mean, isn't two-dimensional array a <strike>continuous</strike> contiguous section of memory? Does the following code work only by luck? Any suggestion is appreciated!

```
    unit Unit5;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs;

    type
      TAADouble = array of array of Double;

      TForm5 = class(TForm)
        procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form5: TForm5;

    procedure SwapRows(arr: TAADouble; row0, row1: Integer);

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure SwapRows(arr: TAADouble; row0, row1: Integer);
    var
      Tmp: Integer;
    begin
      {$IFDEF FPC}
      Tmp := PtrUInt(arr[row0]);
      PtrUInt(arr[row0]) := PtrUInt(arr[row1]);
      PtrUInt(arr[row1]) := Tmp;
      {$ELSE}
      Tmp := Integer(arr[row0]);
      Integer(arr[row0]) := Integer(arr[row1]);
      Integer(arr[row1]) := Tmp;
      {$ENDIF}

    end;

    procedure TForm5.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    var
      tmpArray: TAADouble;
      I, J: Integer;
      rowStr: string;
    begin
      SetLength(tmpArray, 10, 10);
      rowStr := '';

      for I := 0 to 9 do
        for J := 0 to 9 do
          tmpArray[I][J] := I * J;

      for I := 0 to 9 do
      begin
        rowStr := '';
        for J := 0 to 9 do
          rowStr := rowStr + FloatToStr(tmpArray[I][J]) + '  ';
        OutputDebugString(PWideChar(rowStr));
      end;

      SwapRows(tmpArray, 3, 4);

      for I := 0 to 9 do
      begin
        rowStr := '';
        for J := 0 to 9 do
          rowStr := rowStr + FloatToStr(tmpArray[I][J]) + '  ';
        OutputDebugString(PWideChar(rowStr));
      end;
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: While the above works (at the moment), casting a pointer to an Integer is not safe - this will fail miserably when the 64-bit version arrives... if you are using a recent Delphi, use the NativeInt type, otherwise define your own that you can set to match the pointer size yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask:

> Does the following code work only by
>   luck?

Well, yes, you are relying on implementation specific details.

In fact the correct way to write it is perfectly natural and simple:

```
type
  TDoubleArray = array of Double;
  TDoubleMatrix = array of TDoubleArray;

procedure SwapRows(M: TDoubleMatrix; Row1, Row2: Integer);
var
  Temp: TDoubleArray;
begin
  Temp := M[Row1];
  M[Row1] := M[Row2];
  M[Row2] := Temp;
end;
```

You need to declare an intermediate type for the row, TDoubleArray, so that you can perform the assignment to Temp in the swap routine.

A 2D constant size array

```
array [1..M] of array [1..N] of TMyType
```

is a contiguous block of memory.

A 2D dynamically size array as you have is not. Indeed it can even be ragged in the sense that the rows have different numbers of columns. So you can have, say, a triangular matrix.

Comment: @David: Great to know that `A 2D constant size array is a contiguous block of memory. A 2D dynamically size array as you have is not. Indeed it can even be ragged in the sense that the rows have different numbers of columns.` Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @David: Nonetheless, is it necessary to have the `var` prefix for `TDoubleMatrix`? I mean, should I expect strange errors if the `var` prefix is absent?

Comment: @Xichen No it is not. I do that out of habit I suppose. It will work perfectly without it. I don't feel there's a compelling reason to do it with or without the var, it's just my habit.

Comment: I have often seen arguments 'erroneously' declared as `var` because the developer thinks they're modifying the input. This is especially common when objets are passed into methods. `var` is not needed to modify the state of an object, but use of `var` actually implies the object can be replaced with a completely different instance. This is a subtle difference between passing by _reference_ and passing by _value_. A dynamic array is always passed by reference, so `var` permits you to replace the entire array.

Comment: @Craig Yes, that's exactly what's going on in my mind. Reference types make a mockery of var and const though.

Comment: Somehow, I thought dynamic arrays featured the same "copy-on-write" behavior that strings have. Simple test just shown me wrong... It must be noted though that doing the equivalent for a string would require the "var" keyword.  Also, using the "const" keyword will usually allow the compiler to do some additional optimisations, in this situation, removing a call to @DynArrayAddRef.

Comment: @Ken Exactly. It's precisely the fact that dynamic arrays don't do copy-on-write that makes this all work. Copy-on-write for dynamic arrays would be disastrous because they are often backed by very large blocks of memory.

Answer (score 4):

A dynamic array is implemented as a pointer to a memory block representing that array. So a two-dimensional dynamic array is actually a pointer to an array of pointers. Thats why swapping the row(-pointer)s actually works.

See David's answer for a cleaner approach.

**Update:**
If you are allowed to use generics you might as well do this:

```
procedure <SomeClassOrRecord>.SwapRows<T>(var arr: TArray<T>; row0, row1: Integer);
var
  Tmp: T;
begin
  Tmp := arr[row0];
  arr[row0] := arr[row1];
  arr[row1] := Tmp;
end;
```

Comment: @David: Could you help to comment what do you mean by `It won't work if the reference counts of the rows are different.`?

Comment: @Xichen No I was getting confused, that statement is not correct.

Comment: As David's comment vanished, I guess he realised that swapping the pointers will also swap the ref counts as they are located in front of the array and not at the pointer to it. Otherwise the ref-counting probably wouldn't work.

Comment: @David, @Uwe: Thanks! I will switch to David's approach because it does not involve converting pointer to integer and thus I will not need to worry about the `IfDef` between Integer/Cardinal/NativeInt/NativeUInt/PtrInt/PrtUInt.

Comment: @Uwe: Thanks for your sample code of swapping using generics!